# using methods within templates in c++

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to get basic view of templates and i'm very confused. I have 3 classes, each based on template:

```
#include <map>

using namespace std;

typedef void (*cb1)(int a, int b);
typedef void (*cb2)(int a, int b, int c);

template <class H>
class CHandle{
    H m_id;
};

template <typename H>
class HndFactory {
public:
    CHandle<H>* createHandle() {
        return new CHandle<H>();
    }
};

template <typename H>
CHandle<H> *createHandle(){
    CHandle<H> *h = new CHandle<H>();
    h->m_id = 100;
    return h;
}

template <class S>
class CSubscriber{
    S m_proc;
};

template <class H, class S>
class CEvent{
    H m_handle;
    S m_subscriber;
    std::map<CHandle<H>, CSubscriber<S> > m_map;
public:
    void subscribe(CHandle<H> *h);
    void unsubscribe(CHandle<H> *h);
};
template <class H, class S>
void CEvent<H, S>::subscribe(CHandle<H> *h){

}
int main(void){
    HndFactory<int> f;
    CSubscriber<cb1> s;
    CHandle<int> *h = f.createHandle();
    CEvent<CHandle<int>, CSubscriber<cb1> > myevent;
    myevent.subscribe(h);
    return 0;
}
```

when i'm trying to run method "`myevent.subscribe`" i got this compiler error:

```
CGlue.cpp: In function âint main()â:
CGlue.cpp:64: error: no matching function for call to âCEvent<CHandle<int>, CSubscriber<void (*)(int, int)> >::subscribe(CHandle<int>*&)â
CGlue.cpp:54: note: candidates are: void CEvent<H, S>::subscribe(CHandle<H>*) [with H = CHandle<int>, S = CSubscriber<void (*)(int, int)>]
```

How shall i call this method in a proper way ? I tought that when i create object '`h`' it has already defined type ?

best regards
J.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either need to change your class members to

```
std::map<H, S> m_map;

void subscribe(H *h);
void unsubscribe(CHandle<H> *h);
```

or

Your `CEvent` object should be declared as

```
CEvent<int, cb1> myevent;
```

You have to make one of these 2 changes.

Your current code does the template thing twice.
With

```
template <class H, class S>
class CEvent{
```

and

```
CEvent<CHandle<int>, CSubscriber<cb1> > myevent;
```

what you have is

```
H == CHandle<int> & S = CSubscribe<cb1>
```

So

```
void subscribe(CHandle<H> *h);
```

becomes

```
void subscribe(<CHandle<CHandle<H> > * h);
```

once the template is instantiated.

Answer (score 2):

```
CEvent<CHandle<int>, CSubscriber<cb1> > myevent;
```

should be

```
CEvent<int, cb1> myevent;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message actually tells you what's wrong here with a little digging into its details:

`candidates are: void CEvent<H, S>::subscribe(CHandle<H>*) [with H = CHandle<int>`

From this we see that the candidate method is listed, with template type and the type being deduced for `H`. When you substitute H with the type in question you get a candidate of:

`void CEvent<H, S>::subscribe(CHandle<CHandle<int> >*)` which now hopefully clearly doesn't match the `CHandle<int>` being passed in.

Instead, I think you want to use `CEvent<int, cb1> myevent;` as your event object. Note that you may wish to use a typedef for the various handle and subscriber types within the `CEvent` class as it may make future maintenance easier.